# I want to create parent and child relation between a list of objects in a javascript, based on common property value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have object list like below :->

```
[
{inputFileName: "file1.xlsx",versionId: 1},
{inputFileName: "file1.xlsx",versionId: 2},
{inputFileName: "file2.xlsx",versionId: 1},
{inputFileName: "file2.xlsx",versionId: 2},
]
```

I want to achieve parent and child relationship by adding new object with some properties id and managerId like below :->

```
[
{inputFileName: "file1.xlsx",versionId: null,id : 1,managerId : null},
{inputFileName: "file1.xlsx",versionId: 1,id : 2,managerId : 1},
{inputFileName: "file1.xlsx",versionId: 2,id : 3,managerId : 1},
{inputFileName: "file2.xlsx",versionId: null,id : 4,managerId : null},
{inputFileName: "file2.xlsx",versionId: 1,id : 5,managerId : 4},
{inputFileName: "file2.xlsx",versionId: 2,id : 6,managerId : 4},
]
```

In above new array we have added new object for objects which has same file name with id as some value and manager id as null, in a similar way I have to implement how can achieve this.

Comment: where are `filename`, `title`, `date` and `hireDate` conjured from? why do some have `date` and others not? how do you get from the first to second object? where does `id` and `managerId` come from? why are there two extra objects? why does some have a `versionId` of null - it looks like you need a magic trick rather than code :D

Comment: Actually 3rd object is just for reference, to understand the logic. in that you can see all the objects has id and managerId, so based on that we can conclude that objects which has managrid will be child and which is null will parent. first object is what i have right now and second object is what i am expecting

Comment: i think because of 3rd object people may get confused, so i will be deleting it.

Comment: even the second makes no sense ... you suddenly have 2 extra objects, with two extra properties each, with no explanation of where they came from

Comment: Thats what i have explained that, we need to add new object for group of objects which has same inputFileName  with id and managerId, for that managerId will be null always and you can give any value to id, so the same id will become as managerId in all child objects.

Comment: it means 1,2 has same inputFileName, for that we need add new object with id and managerId. in similar way for 3,4th object also. whenever we are adding new object will have managerId as null and id might be any integer value

Comment: where does the managerId/id relationship come from? is it just two id's that share a managerId ... just made up like that on a whim? well, that should be easy - show what you tried

Comment: You can co-relate with team managers and team workers, both will have id ID's which are uniques, but team workers who comes under specific manager will have managerId as id of manager.  this relation we need to achieve